# messagebox popup at form load but no messagebox included in the application

Tags: c#

I am facing a problem in C# windows forms **MessageBox.Show( )**

I just added a **MessageBox** in a function and then called it in the **Form_Load** event, Just to Test values set in **Project->Properties->Settings**

Now as my results were confirmed, I deleted the **MessageBox.Show( )** from the function and restarted the application but the message box is still being poped up. I have gone through my code many times Searched all **MessageBox** in the code but there is no reference to that specific problem in the code.

I have no clue. my application is almost of 4560 line of code. I used **Ctrl + F** to search the **MessageBox** and I have also checked every line all by my self to make sure if there is any possible blunder on my side but all in vain.

Ask if you want any other information.

Comment: did you rebuild your program?

Comment: are you able to debug your program?

Comment: is it the same messagebox text as the messagebox that you removed?

Comment: Looks like your application is not being rebuilt, and the old .exe runs. A possible cause is build errors. Try Clean Solution, or try deleting the exe from bin\Debug.

Comment: @Default Yes it was rebuild error, thank you man

Comment: @PeterB for some reason my application was unable to rebuild solution. Now it works fine. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Last day I puzzled with same issue you have. For me I deploy the new code on server but code is not new as I upload so I try with delete the bin and upload again, result are still same.

I delete the whole app from server and put the app again and it's work fine. In your case try with delete the bin folder, and obj folder and see if it's work for you.

Comment: For some reason my application was not able to rebuild so I try this simple solution and it work fine now. @Anirudha Gupta

Comment: so I assume it's work now. please share how you fix the issue?